# TabPageIndicator (for ViewPager) background is black on Gingerbread devices

Tags: android, android-viewpager, viewpagerindicator

I'm using Jake Whartons viewpagerindicator lib.

On ICS+ devices the backgroudn for TabPageIndicator looks like it should:

[image]

But on a GingerBread device it looks like this:

[image]

Code for the style:

```
<style name="TabStyle" parent="Widget.TabPageIndicator">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/custom_tab_indicator</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#FF555555</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">8dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">8dp</item>
    <item name="android:fadingEdge">horizontal</item>
    <item name="android:fadingEdgeLength">8dp</item>
</style>
```

I've tried setting the background to just one color, it works, but then I have no red strip.

I've also desperately tried things like setting android:cacheColorHint="#00000000" on the indicator cause it seemed like a similar problem that the ListView has.

I've also tried setting the app theme to Theme.Sherlock.Light for devices lower than API 14. (Current theme is Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionbar).

**Please help me make the background white as it should be.**

Comment: what theme you are using for GB devices?

Comment: I'm using ABS theme Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar

Comment: you can try Theme.Sherlock.Light for below 11 API,hope that will work.:)

Comment: Thanks, tried it, but no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so I've figured it out. All I needed to do is to set the background for the Indicator View itself:

```
 <com.viewpagerindicator.TabPageIndicator
        android:id="@+id/indicator"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/vpi__background_holo_light"
        />
```

Where vpi__background_holo_light is a light color.

Hope this helps someone.